# What is wrong with this unix command when i try it via ssh?

Tags: bash, unix

When i run the below command:

```
ssh $HOST1 for dir in /local/apps/*; do ls -lrt $dir | grep live ; done
```

I get the below error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

It works fine without ssh when doing locally.

I even tried

```
ssh $HOST1 "for dir in /local/apps/*; do ls -lrt $dir | grep live ; done"
```

But this gave an unexpected result. What is the correct format for doing a for loop via ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
ssh $HOST1 'for dir in /local/apps/*; do ls -lrt $dir | grep live ; done'
```

With double quotes, that `$dir` will be being expanded on the local machine, not as part of the remote SSH command.

Just for reference, the reason

```
ssh $HOST1 for dir in /local/apps/*; do ls -lrt $dir | grep live ; done
```

doesn't work is because it is interpreted as

```
ssh $HOST1 'for dir in /local/apps/*'
do ls -lrt $dir | grep live
done
```

with the `for` running under SSH on the remote machine, and `do` and `done` running locally.